# Selecting and displaying all of items with same value in attribute table using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, select-by-attribute, definition-query

One of the columns in my attribute table is entitled NAICS_1 and I'm supposed to display only the objects with an NAICS_1 of a specific value.

How do I filter the attribute table using ArcMap to only select and display the specific value?

Comment: You have a tag for Definition Query.  Have you looked at the documentation to see how to use one of those?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a guide for [ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/tables/filter-data-in-the-table.htm) and  one for [ArcMap](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/filtering-the-data-source-using-attributes.htm)

For ArcGIS Pro (since that's the one I have installed), right click the layer, go to Properties at the bottom, and go to Definition Query:

[image]

There you can add a condition. For instance, to only show 'Coastline' features in the [Natural Earth Coastline dataset](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/), you would add a filter that looks like this:

[image]

Apply and you're done.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks friends!

Comment: If friends helped you, mark solution as correct please.